# Azure AD B2C - edit profile bespoke application?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

After investigating what Azure AD B2C can do, I'm not sure if it can do everything we need it to do through custom policies / we would have to make some compromises. I was thinking of still using it purely for authentication actions against our users: sign in or sign up - local & social media accounts, reset password etc.

However, we also want to collect more details about the user that they either provide at sign up or at a later date, and I'm finding the ability to edit profiles quite lacking.

Therefore I was thinking instead to create a bespoke dot net core or framework application which will act as a 'preference centre' that the user goes through. We will have much greater customisation o this, as we will not be limited to what Microsoft allow through custom policies. The user would either be passed through this application after signing in and before reaching one of our applications, or they can get to it from a link on our applications. All the data that is stored for the user will still be held in the Users section in our Azure AD B2C. Then the application will use the Graph API to query and update the data for the user.

Is this a sensible approach? Or can you recommend something else?

Comment: What exactly is lacking in the edit profile?

Comment: We want to be able to break the process into several screens. So the first would be a list of buttons which takes the user off to one of the screens for each area of the user's profile. When a user has then saved that are of their profile, this would take them back to the first screen. They would then be able to return to the original application from this screen as well. I don't see an easy way of doing this with B2C.

Comment: @pengiun178 [Custom policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-overview#:~:text=Custom%20policies%20are%20configuration%20files,to%20complete%20many%20different%20tasks.) is fully capable of achieving all that.

Comment: @AlfredoR.-MSFTIdentity unfortunately, we've not seen any documentation anywhere that would suggest a custom policy with level of customisation is possible. Are there any samples anywhere that would give us at least a guide on how to start a custom policy like this?